# Java/RXJava3 error when building from another source

Tags: java, intellij-idea, rx-java

```
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\ExternalPlugins-master\PerfectSpec\src\main\java\net\runelite\client\plugins\perfectspec\MenuEntrySwapConsumer.java:47: error: cannot access Consumer
        eventBus.subscribe(MenuOptionClicked.class, this, this::onMenuOptionClicked);
                ^
  class file for io.reactivex.rxjava3.functions.Consumer not found
```

I'm a bit new to Java and I'm trying to build my program using code from another source, but I'm getting this error. I'm using Intellij, anyone know how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have the corresponding library jar added to the [module dependencies](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html#working-with-module-dependencies)?

Comment: I've just tried that, but it gives the same error. sorry for the wait

Comment: Please share a sample project.

Comment: https://easyupload.io/cseewo , the error part is under the PerfectSpec -> src -> main -> java folders on the left, in the "MenuEntrySwapConsumer" and "MenuEntrySwapHandler" files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This project build file has invalid dependency. It imports `rxjava2` library, while using `rxjava3` in the code.

To fix the problem you need to edit `Dependencies.kt:46` and change it to `const val rxjava = "io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxjava:${Versions.rxjava}"`.

Then at `Dependencies.kt:38` change to `const val rxjava = "3.0.1"`.

Then comment these lines:

- `build.gradle.kts:15` (`implementation("io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxjava:3.0.1")`)
- `PerfectSpec/perfectspec.gradle.kts:38` (`compileOnly("io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.19")`)

There is also a typo at `net/runelite/client/plugins/externals/perfectspec/MenuEntrySwapConsumer.java:48`, this line should probably look like this: `eventBus.subscribe(MenuEntryAdded.class, this, this::onMenuEntryAdded);`.

After these changes the project imports and builds without errors for me.